# How to dump all the URLs opened in firefox

Tags: shell-script, firefox

Imagine a situation you are self-studying, and you suddenly remember that you need to submit an assignment tomorrow, so you need to do those stuff now. Now, you close your tabs and open new websites regarding your work. After all the things have taken care of you need the old tabs, which are already closed. Now you search them in history and all over the places and waste a lot of time.

I want to run a script that dumps all the URLs that are opened currently in firefox, from which I can restore the old sessions using `xargs` or something like that. Bookmarking doesn't seem a solution, because I never find them when needed.

I thought this might help

```
lsof -ai
```

But this is not useful. Can this be down with some bash scripting?
If not possible I would try to make something using `xdotool`

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic, as I will try to show you that bookmarking is not that bad. All you need is a good name for a session that you save.

When you right-click on the tabs, you can choose `Bookmark All Tabs`. Then a popup appears and you name the folder that will hold all the tabs.

Restoring a session is also that easy. In the bookmarks find the session folder, right-click and choose `Open All in Tabs`.

Answer (score 0):

The [OneTab extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/onetab/?src=search) does precisely that. It's also available for Chromium/Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox 69 and method suggested at
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1221836 works for me.

Shortly, a list of currently opened tabs is stored in
`<fx_profile>/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4`. As the name
indicates, it's a JSON file compressed using LZ4 compression.

Make a backup of it and use this online tool to dump a list of opened
tabs: https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html.

Answer (score 0):

Arkadiusz's answer was very good, but the problem was that the `recovery.jsonlz4` file contained so much of data about which I was not sure how to process. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1221836 gave a nice hint how to do it.

I wrote a `dmenu` wrapper bash script that copies that copies the file `recovery.jsonlz4` itself to some location with a given name and restores when asked for.

```
#!/bin/bash
SESSIONS="$HOME/.netsessions/"
PROFILE="$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/<use-your-profile>.default/"
[[ ! -d $PROFILE ]] && notify-send Firefox "Profile was not found" && exit 0
[[ ! -d $SESSIONS ]] && mkdir -p $SESSIONS
fireicon=/usr/share/icons/Paper/512x512/apps/firefox.png
subs=`ls "$SESSIONS"`
opt=$(echo -e "Create\nOpen\nDelete"| dmenu -fn "Droid Sans Mono-20" -i -p "firefox session:")

[[ "$opt" = "" ]] && exit 1
if [ "$opt" = "Create" ]; then
    (! pidof firefox > /dev/null ) && notify-send -t 1000 -i $fireicon Firefox "Firefox is not running" && exit 1
    opt1=$(echo "$subs"|dmenu -fn 'Droid Sans Mono-20' -i -p "Name it to create") 
    if [ -z "$opt1" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    cp $PROFILE/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 $SESSIONS/$opt1 > /dev/null && notify-send -t 1000 -i $fireicon Firefox "Session created" && exit 0
elif [ "$opt" = "Open" ]; then
    opt2=$(echo "$subs"|dmenu -fn 'Droid Sans Mono-20' -i -p "Name it to open") 
    if [ -z "$opt2" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    killall firefox >/dev/null 2>&1
    cp $SESSIONS/$opt2 $PROFILE/sessionstore.jsonlz4 > /dev/null
    setsid firefox >/dev/null 2>&1 &
elif [ "$opt" = "Delete" ]; then
    opt3=$(echo "$subs"|dmenu -fn 'Droid Sans Mono-15' -i -p "Name it to delete") 
    if [ -z "$opt3" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    rm "$SESSIONS"/"$opt3" > /dev/null && notify-send -t 1000 -i $fireicon group "Session deleted" && exit 0
elif [ -z "$opt" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

I used a key-binding to call this script. Let me know if any improvements can be done.
**PS:** I'm using firefox 69